# ffmpeg for loop into bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop, ffmpeg

I use a for loop on the mac command line to convert a bunch of avi's to mp4's
I would like to put this into a bash script so I can just run the script on any given directory.

e.g {shelf script name} [directory}

and let it do its thing.

Do I just open a text editor and add

```
#!/bin/bash
```

then my for loop and ffmpeg arguments
then end it all with
fi ?

Then make it executable ? Is is that simple.

@Robert Rowntree

Many thanks for the link. This looks like it could be very useful to me. I am not familiar with the concatenate so I would have never found that information.

It appears that I can give ffmpeg a bunch of files at the command line or to read from a text file and ffmpeg will output them all into a single format, In my case MP4's. Well at least this is what I *think* it does.

The "The inputs have to be of the same frame size, and a handful of other attributes have to match" worries me a bit, do i need to check the frame rate of every movie to ensure they all match ?

My ultimate goal would be to run a script on say, 30 mixed video files, avi, wmv, mkv, mpg etc and output the lot to mp4, but I think this is way too complicated for me.

I normally just repack mkv's to mp4 and the quality and size are good and I'm pleased with the results and speed. However, I tried just repacking a the aforementioned avi's and the quality was poor and pixelated. I searched around and finally found this example;

ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -ac 2 out.mp4  (can this be improved ? Sped up ?)

Which produces great quality mp4 files from the avi's I have got but does take a long time. Hence why I originally asked for help creating a script. Which I intended running on the folder of avi's.

Be great to be able just to run a script on every non mp4 files and have great results every time :) But with different codecs and frame rates etc etc I suppose this will never be possible.

Any further help or input will be greatly received.

Thanks again.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate   see sample scripts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it's that simple. You should read bash's man page, i.e.

```
man bash
```

and a bit about shell programming online.

Comment: "thank you" on stack overflow is equivalent to an upvote and/or an accepted answer ;) But you're really welcome!

Comment: @jm666 the RTFM was just an addition. His question was "is this really this easy", and "yes" seemed a bit short.